Using AzureAD to generate report with user's groups and manager
I am modifying a script I made awhile back and wanted to get some guidance.
Currently, the script just grabs a list of all the groups a user is a member of and exports them to a .csv file. However, I am also trying to get the user's manager's email onto that spreadsheet so I can email them the list. I can get it to grab the Manager from AD, but I am struggling a bit of how I can get their email onto the spreadsheet.
Here is my script at the moment
Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user | Get-AzureADUserManager | Get-AzureADUserMembership | % {Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | select DisplayName,Description} | Export-csv -Path C:\temp\GroupList.csv
'Manager Email' 
Write-Output $manager

Edit: Here's how the information comes out now
DisplayName | Description
ExampleGroup| Example Group

Here's how I'd like it to come out:
DisplayName | Description | Manager
ExampleGroup| ExampleGroup| example.manager@domain.com


It's unclear how should the CSV output look like. Please add this information to the question.

I've added the details you requested. Please take a look when you have some time

@Glitch Is this below solution works for you?

Unfortunately no, its just exporting as a blank spreadsheet

What if a user is member of more than 1 group? Does the manager column always have the same manager per group?

@Glitch Is this below solution works for you?

Try following :
$table = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $user | Get-AzureADUserManager | Get-AzureADUserMembership | % {Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | select DisplayName,Description}
foreach($row in $table)
{
   $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Manager -NotePropertyValue $Manager
} 
$table | Export-csv -Path C:\temp\GroupList.csv


This is not exporting the data correctly, all I see is a blank spreadsheet

@Glitch Are you looking for such kind of output

This is the csv file output

Do you get any output if you type after you run the cmdlet : $table | Format-List


Using AzureAD to generate report with user's groups and manager

To get DisplayName , Description and Users_ManagerMail onto the spreadsheet, Use below powershell script:
 $users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

$table = @()

foreach ($user in $users) {
  $manager = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $user.ObjectId
  if ($manager -ne $null) {
    $managerEmail = $manager.Mail
  } else {
    $managerEmail = "No Manager"
  }

  $groupMemberships = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user.ObjectId

  foreach ($group in $groupMemberships) {
    $groupInfo = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $group.ObjectId | select DisplayName, Description
    $groupInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Manager -NotePropertyValue $managerEmail
    
    $table += $groupInfo
  }
}

$table | Select-Object DisplayName, Description, Manager  | Format-Table


OUTPUT:

To export above output into csv file  use below command:
$table  |Select-Object DisplayName , Description, Manager| Export-Csv  -Path <FilePath> -NoTypeInformation


Reference:
Get-AzureADUserManager 
